# Navigating in context menu with Selenium webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How I can navigate through context menu (arrow up or down and then enter) of an image in Chrome using Selenium webdriver with Ruby? It opens the menu but can't select anything. This is the part of the code

```
driver.find_element(:id, "icImg").click
  el = driver.find_element(:id, "viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr")
  driver.action.context_click(el).perform
```

Can't find any information how to select something from the menu.

Comment: Is it possible that you can offer me the site url you are automating?

Comment: I try it with Ebay.com, the first add i see, the exact link is:[link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-rolls-Official-eBay-Branded-BOPP-Packaging-Scotch-Tape-shipping-supplies-sale/292172341592?epid=513104903&hash=item4406d42158:g:yrIAAOSw5cNYbTu1) click on the first image to enlarge. The chromepath give this as path: //img[@id='viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr'], the context menu was not a problem but can't select option.

Comment: I don't see any matching element with this xpath `//img[@id='viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr']`. Better update your whole program. I don't know where you click

Comment: `class Helper
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
    
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  
      driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-rolls-Official-eBay-Branded-BOPP-Packaging-Scotch-Tape-shipping-supplies-sale/292172341592?epid=513104903&hash=item4406d42158:g:yrIAAOSw5cNYbTu1")
      driver.find_element(:id, "icImg").click
      el = driver.find_element(:id, "viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr")
      driver.action.context_click(el).perform
end`

Comment: This is the whole program and it works to the context menu